# Migration is currently disabled for 'Web App Bot' bots

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-web-app-service

Yesterday I received an email from Azure Team talking about "Azure Bot Service" and the need to migrate to the Bot Service registration.

When I try to migrate my bots I receive the message below:

"Migration is currently disabled for 'Web App Bot' bots".

However, the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-migrate-bot), under the "Migration under the hood" part, cover this kind of service.

Anyone else with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently only Bot Registrations are supported for migration (2018-01-02).  If you have a bot registration that was created in the Bot Developer Portal at https://dev.botframework.com, you can migrate your registration to the new Azure product called "Bot Channels Registration".

Other types of bots are not supported for migration at this time. For example pre-GA "Azure Bot Service (Preview)" bots, both functions app, and web app type cannot be "migrated".

The best practice at this time is to create a new "Web App Bot" or "Functions Bot" via the Azure Portal, and point the new instance to your existing bot code via Continuous Integration.

Comment: Do you know how to create "Web App Bot" with Azure REST API? I find nothing about it. We need to create it remotely, not manually in Azure portal... Any ideas?